# Extract emails from a string soup in python

Tags: python

I have a string of html page, and I want to extract emails from that string without using re.findAll() function.

This is what I tried and worked, but looking for something to make me understand it more.

```
  url_html = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(url_html, "html.parser")
  soup = str(soup)
  emails = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', soup)
```

Comment: Please also include the HTML content so that readers of your question may know how to parse for email addresess.

Comment: You can always manually reimplement `re.findall`, but to be honest there's not much you're going to learn about email addresses by writing a state machine. It's too reductionist, like trying to learn how to drive a car by reading a book on internal combustion engines. I recommend a good tutorial on regular expressions; once you get the hang of it, you'll be able to parse them pretty easily.

Comment: Why do you not like re.findall?  That is certainly an acceptable way to do this task, although if you're doing this to get addresses for spam lists, I'd really rather you didn't.

Comment: No it was for school purpose only, I was required to implement the program rather than using a simple function.